# A terminal based atom feed reader written in golang

Tags: beginner, unit-testing, go, mocks

I'm a beginner trying to get a better understanding of golang so I decided to write an atom feeder that runs from the terminal.

I am using the [gofeed](https://github.com/mmcdole/gofeed) library to parse the atom feeds and the [tview](https://github.com/rivo/tview) library to make the terminal ui.

I would like to get some advice on better ways to separate my code from these libraries so its easier to unit test, without having to use a mocking library. Any comments on the code in general would be appreciated.

I've included the three functions that do most of the work, the complete code is on [github](https://github.com/barryodev/clacks).

```
func main() {
    // init threadsafe feed data
    safeFeedData = &SafeFeedData{feedData: make(map[string]FeedDataModel)}

    // init ui elements
    app = tview.NewApplication()

    feedList = tview.NewList().ShowSecondaryText(false)
    feedList.SetBorder(true).SetTitle("Feeds")
    feedList.AddItem("Fetching Feed Data", "", 0, nil)

    entriesList = tview.NewList().ShowSecondaryText(false)
    entriesList.SetBorder(true).SetTitle("Entries")
    entriesList.AddItem("Fetching Feed Data", "", 0, nil)

    entryTextView = tview.NewTextView().
        SetChangedFunc(func() {
            app.Draw()
        })

    entryTextView.SetBorder(true)
    entryTextView.SetTitle("Description")
    entryTextView.SetText("Fetching Feed Data")

    // set up flex layout
    flex := tview.NewFlex().
        AddItem(feedList, 0, 1, false).
        AddItem(tview.NewFlex().SetDirection(tview.FlexRow).
            AddItem(entriesList, 0, 1, false).
            AddItem(entryTextView, 0, 2, false), 0, 2, false)

    // async call to load feed data
    go loadAllFeedDataAndUpdateInterface()

    // call to run tview app
    if uiError := app.SetRoot(flex, true).SetFocus(feedList).Run(); uiError != nil {
        panic(uiError)
    }
}

// This will run asynchronously to fetch atom feeds and load the data into the interface
func loadAllFeedDataAndUpdateInterface() {
    var configError error
    allFeeds, configError = loadJsonConfig()
    if configError != nil {
        panic(configError)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(allFeeds.Feeds); i++ {
        feedData, atomFeedError := loadFeedData(allFeeds.Feeds[i].URL)
        if atomFeedError != nil {
            panic(atomFeedError)
        } else {
            safeFeedData.setSiteData(allFeeds.Feeds[i].URL, feedData)
        }
    }

    // Using QueueUpdateDraw as its a threadsafe way to update tview primitives
    app.QueueUpdateDraw(func() {
        feedList.Clear()
        // add items to feed list
        for _, feed := range allFeeds.Feeds {
            feedData := safeFeedData.GetEntries(feed.URL)
            feedList.AddItem(feedData.name, feed.URL, 0, func() {
                // handle user selecting item by moving focus to entry list
                app.SetFocus(entriesList)
            })
        }

        // handle user changing selected feed item by loading entries list
        feedList.SetChangedFunc(func(i int, feedName string, url string, shortcut rune) {
            loadEntriesIntoList(url)
        })

        // handle user changing selected item of entries list by loading entry text view
        entriesList.SetChangedFunc(func(i int, entryName string, secondaryText string, shortcut rune) {
            loadEntryTextView(i)
        })

        // when user hits escape in entries list, move focus back to feed list
        entriesList.SetDoneFunc(func() {
            app.SetFocus(feedList)
        })

        // load initial state of interface
        loadEntriesIntoList(getSelectedFeedUrl())
        //make sure there's at least one entry in selected
        if len(safeFeedData.GetEntries(getSelectedFeedUrl()).entries) > 0 {
            loadEntryTextView(0)
        }
    })
}

// loadFeedData use gofeed library to load data from atom feed
func loadFeedData(url string) (FeedDataModel, error) {
    fp := gofeed.NewParser()
    fp.UserAgent = "Clacks - Terminal Atom Reader"
    feedData, err := fp.ParseURL(url)
    if err != nil {
        return FeedDataModel{}, errors.New("Error processing atom feed: " + err.Error())
    }

    if len(feedData.Items) > 0 {
        feedName := feedData.Title
        entrySlice := make([]Entry, len(feedData.Items))
        for i, item := range feedData.Items {
            entrySlice[i] = Entry{
                title: html.UnescapeString(strip.StripTags(item.Title)),
                content: strings.TrimSpace(html.UnescapeString(strip.StripTags(item.Description))),
            }
        }
        return FeedDataModel{name: feedName, entries: entrySlice}, nil
    }

    return FeedDataModel{}, nil

}
```